# .htaccess config returns 500

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

if replace string to

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L]
```

worked, but I need link to work as in first version

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^(?:[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Alireza now 404

Comment: I would leave both rewrite rules but start with the one for articles and then put the second rewrite rule below. If the first matches (for articles) then I expect it to stop as you used the `L = Last rewrite rule` option.

Comment: @PatrickJanser Maybe I wrote wrong, sorry, just RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L], that is, links like domain.com/paris, domain.com/london

Comment: but for some reason it doesn't work as it should

Comment: Oh, I finally understood your problem! It was due to infinite redirections. I finally tried your problem in live to discover it. I corrected my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

### Your problem is due to infinite internal redirections

### Solution A : add a rewrite condition

```apache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The rewrite condition takes the request URI and tests that it is not matching the `/landing/` path. This way, you avoid having this infinite rewrite loop. Yes, you would say *"But there's the `L` option to say that it's the last"*. Well, yes, we could think it stops there, but no, Apache will take the result of the rewrite rules  and pass them all again until the URL stops changing. It's made like that so that you can have a bunch of rules doing different things, such as one cleaning the URL and then others doing some internal or external redirections.

The `QSA` option will take the previous query string arguments and put them in the resulting internal URL. Example:

```txt
/geneva?show-restaurants=1
```

If I have a PHP script `landing/index.php` with this:

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$debug = [
    'REQUEST_URI' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],
    'QUERY_STRING' => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],
    '$_GET' => $_GET,
];

var_export($debug);
```

This will output the following:

```txt
array (
  'REQUEST_URI' => '/geneva?show-restaurants=4',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/landing/index.php',
  'QUERY_STRING' => 'city=geneva&show-restaurants=4',
  '$_GET' => 
  array (
    'city' => 'geneva',
    'show-restaurants' => '4',
  ),
)
```

So, as you see, you get the *city* and the *show-restaurants* query arguments.

### Solution B : use a negative lookahead in the regex

```apache
RewriteRule ^(?!/?landing/)([^\/]+)\/?$ /landing/?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you see I added the `(?!/?landing/)` in front where `(?! )` is a negative lookahead and where `/?landing/` is to match `/landing/` or `landing/`.

The solution B isn't very clear but no rewrite condition has to be executed so perhaps it's slightly faster.